# Help running NUnit from dos command line

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I am working on an MSBuilds script to run my NUnit tests from CruiseControl.Net.   _Test_DAL  has three tests in it.

I am having problem getting the right dos command to run the NUnit.

Here is the command to run NUnit but it does not find any tests.

> D:\CC\JCDCHelper\Source_Test_DAL\bin\Debug>"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.3\bin\nunit-console" /nologo _Test_DAL.dll
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Not run: 0, Time: 0.047 seconds

I am able to use resharper to run the tests, so I know the tests are written correctly.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Have you try passing it the full path of your dll?

Comment: I tried putting the full path to test dll,  no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going back answering questions i asked that were solved independantly.

We use Powershell now, but here is how we solved it in case it's useful to anyone

```
function Invoke-UnitTests  { 

  $NUnitExe = "C:\" + $WhereIsProgramFiles + "\NUnit 2.5.7\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe"
  Show-Status "Invoke-UnitTests was called."
  Show-Status $NUnitExe

  foreach( $OneProject in ( $TestProjects))
  {
    Show-Status "Running unit test for $OneProject"

    $GetCommonDlls = "D:\CC\$AppName\Source\$AppName\_CommonDlls"
    $GetBinDlls = "D:\CC\$AppName\Source\$AppName\Bin"
    Copy-Item "$GetCommonDlls\*" "$WorkingDir" 
    Copy-Item "$GetBinDlls\*" "$WorkingDir" 

    $WorkingDir = "D:\CC\$AppName\Source\$OneProject\obj\$ReleaseOrDebug"
    $NUnitOutput = "D:\CC\$AppName\NUnit\" + $OneProject + ".xml"

    & "$NUnitExe" "$WorkingDir\$OneProject.DLL" /nologo /xml:$NUnitOutput
    if ($lastExitCode -ne 0) 
    {
        Show-Status "NUnit test Command failed for Project:$ProjectName in Application:$AppName”
        Show-Status "Command that failed: ""$NUnitExe"" ""$WorkingDir\$OneProject.DLL"" /nologo /xml:$NUnitOutput"
        Show-Error “Error: Unit test for $OneProject failed”
    }
  }

  Show-Status "All Done with Unit tests"    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The input files have to go first, then the options.

nunit-console _Test_DAL.dll /nologo

Comment: Using NUnit 2.4.8, I am able to specify /nologo first and still run tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Resharper handles tests, but I do recall TestDriven.Net as being able to 'run test' on methods that were not actually marked as unit tests.  Make sure your class is public and marked as a [TestFixture], and that the unit test is a public void method marked as a [Test].